# Why does every element in my array start with "null"?

Tags: java

I want to make a random color code generator and it also works, but instead of simply giving me the color it also spits out "null" right before it.

So in the end my output looks like `[nullBlue, nullgreen, nullyellow, nullred]` anybody know a quick fix?

```
public class rndmcode {

    int[] secretcode = new int[4];
    String[] farbcode = new String[4];

    public rndmcode() { // array "secretcode" wird definiert
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { //Schleife um eine Randomziffer von 1-6 zu erstellen und
            
            Random zufallszahl = new Random();
            int rndnumber = zufallszahl.nextInt(7); //Die Zahlen 1-6 sind meine Farben, die vorrerst nur Zahlen sind

            switch (rndnumber) {
                case 1:
                    farbcode[i] += "Blau";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    farbcode[i] += "Rot";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    farbcode[i] += "Gelb";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    farbcode[i] += "Grün";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    farbcode[i] += "Lila";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    farbcode[i] += "Orange";
                default:
                    if (farbcode == null)
                        break;
            }
        }
    }

    public String stringo() {
        String s = "[";
        for (String element : farbcode) {
            s += element;
            s += ", ";

        }
        s += "]";
        return s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an array in Java, the elements in the array will initially have a default value. For non-primitives, this value is `null`. So `farbcode = new String[4]` will create a new array that can store 4 `String`'s, but initially it will contain 4 `null` values.

You use `farbcode[i] += "Some value"` with `farbcode[i]` initially being `null`. When you append a String to a `null` value, the `null` will be converted to the string `"null"`, to which the string will be appended.

So for example

```
String str = null + "String"; // Will become "nullString"
```

```
String str = null;
str += "String"; // Same as above
```

So, to prevent this from happening, make sure that the elements in the array don't contain the value `null` when appending values to it.

You can use `Arrays.fill(farbcode, "");` to set all the elements in the array to an empty string at the beginning of your loop.

As an aside, Java has a built-in function to convert an array to a string. You can replace your `stringo()` function with `Arrays.toString(farbcode)`.